# How could I find out the old file name in Azure DevOps?

Tags: file, azure-devops, rename, filenames, git-commit

I moved a file one folder up. Now in Azure DevOps in commit content I see `[rename]` written next to the file, but I do not see how the file name was changed (i.e. I do not see the old file name). Is there any way I could find this out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hovering over the file name in the commit content diff explorer shows a title containing the information I was looking for. It says `{new branch name} [rename] renamed from {old branch name}`.

Would be nice not to have to hover over to see this though. Since sometimes there are a lot of files. Hopefully Microsoft will add another way to view this in future.